# Converting decimal to Binary representation

Tags: erlang

I am having issue in converting decimal to binary representation in Erlang. The code is not for a particular decimal number but it should be for all decimal number we want to convert. But I am trying to print binary values in reverse order. e.g., binary value of 10 = [1,0,1,0] but I want that it should print [0,1,0,1].

Any suggestion please!

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the number to a binary, convert the binary to a list of bits, drop all leading zero bits, then reverse the result:

```
1> N = 10.
10
2> lists:reverse(lists:dropwhile(fun(D) -> D =:= 0 end, [X || <<X:1>> <= <<N:64>>])).
[0,1,0,1]
```

This example represents the number as a 64-bit binary, but you can make it larger if you expect to have to deal with bigger numbers. Also, this solution returns an empty list for a value of 0; to fix that, just pattern-match and return `[0]` for that case. This approach is shown in the form of function clauses below:

```
convert(0) -> [0];
convert(N) ->
    lists:reverse(lists:dropwhile(fun(D) -> D =:= 0 end, [X || <<X:1>> <= <<N:64>>])).
```

Comment: Thank you very much Steve.:)

Comment: In the same way can we Convert character to binary representation and vice versa 

and apply xor operation on bitstring so that result should be like this :

xor([1,1,0,1,0,1], [1,0,1]) = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1].

Comment: @Guddu: see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vinoski/02d4ae80440ca1f96c2e7ecb188a9088) to see how you can do that.

Comment: Thanks Steve, it was very helpful.

Comment: One more favour please:

Comment: I am trying to convert char to binary  and binary to char. e.g., For char2bin, char2Bit($a) = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0] and for bin2char, bin2Char([1,0,0,0,1,0,1]) = 81 ($Q) as output. Thanks

Comment: @guddu: using the code in the gist, if you also export the `convert/1` and `list2bin/1` functions, then calling `x:convert($a).` returns `[1,0,0,0,0,1,1]` and calling `x:list2bin(([1,0,0,0,1,0,1]).` returns `<<"Q">>`. For the latter, `<<V>> = x:list2bin(([1,0,0,0,1,0,1]), V.` returns 81, which is `$Q`.

Comment: Yeah x:convert($a). returns [1,0,0,0,0,1,1] but if I want return [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]? I tried changing bit values from 64 to 128 but it did not work(Bin = [X || <<X:1>> <= <<N:64>>]).

Comment: @Guddu: to do that, change the 64 to 8, assuming all your characters fit in 8 bits, and then get rid of the `lists:dropwhile` call so that all leading zero bits are retained.

Comment: Also I am implementing encryption/decryption using this xor. For encrytion: Repeat the Key until you the length of the sequence is at least the length of the Text (RepKey).Apply the xor operation on the bitstring representation of Text and RepKey (BitResult) and Create the text representation of the bitstring. Please suggest how can I apply this using xor? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not quite sure which part you're having trouble with. Here's a solution that may help though.

To convert a number to binary:

```
integer_to_list(123, 2)
```

If you want to print out the binary:

```
io:format("~s~n", [integer_to_list(123, 2)]).
```

This appears to be in the reverse order to what you want. Simply reverse the list:

```
io:format("~s~n", [lists:reverse(integer_to_list(123, 2))]).
```

Hope this helps answer the question.

Comment: Thanks Andrakis for response.

Comment: @Guddu I can't reply to the other answer yet, but if you want to apply xor bit operations, you can use the `bxor` Erlang operator like so: `1 bxor 3`. There are a few other such operators in the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81348)